# Horizontal scrolling on window re-size

Tags: html, css

```
#wrapper {
width: 896px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding-top: 760px;
padding-left: 48px;
padding-right: 48px;
color: rgb(60,60,60);
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* Stops Mobile Safari from auto-adjusting font-sizes */
overflow:hidden;
}
```

I'm using Less Framework 4 which is working fine. The only problem is when I re-size the window down a horizontal scrollbar pops up mid-sizing then goes away. I've narrowed it down to my #wrapper DIV as once removed, everything's fine. It seems to be the width but I need a width set as the body is (obviously) 100%. Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using max-width. That will let it shrink down below the value, but not above.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: My pleasure :)
On stackoverflow the equivalent of a virtual kiss would be clicking on the accept tick, and if you're really into it, give it a little bit of upvote! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the width to 100%?
What browser do you use? Note that Firefox adds padding to the width of an element.
You can also try to set overflow-x:hidden to the parent of #wrapper.

Comment: Yeah, tried that but doesn't work unfortunately! That's a workaround but not preferable as it cuts off certain content at a certain width. I'm sure there's an irregularity in my code somewhere but I just can't seem to find it! Here's my CSS file if it helps (http://yyy.comuf.com/style.css)